# c++ oop problem with this how initial "unable to read memory"

Tags: c++, oop

I have a problem as shown on the following image [image]

I have added all the code of the monom.cpp  , 
Probably the problem that I did not set the temp well is the help how to set temp, the result that i should return it's polinom = 0;it's 
The degree of the polynomial and for example I add polynomial x ^ 2 + 1
The degree of the polynomial is 2

```
void  Polinom::add(const Monomial const & monomial)

int base = monomial.getCoff();
int exp = monomial.getExpo();
bool foundBase = false;
Monomial* temp = new Monomial[size + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    Monomial monom;
         monom = monomials[i];
    if (exp == monom.getExpo())
    {
        monom.setCoff(base + monom.getCoff());
        foundBase = true;
    }
    temp[i] = monom;
}
if (!foundBase)
{
    monomials[size] = Monomial(monomial);
    delete[] monomials;
    monomials = temp;
}
else
{
    delete[] temp;
}
```

Monomial.cpp

```
int Monomial::counter = 0;
Monomial::Monomial()
{
setCoff(1);
setExpo(0);
counter++;
}
Monomial::Monomial(int a)
{
 setCoff(a);
 setExpo(0);
 counter++;
}
 Monomial::Monomial(int a, int b)
 {
  setCoff(a);
  setExpo(b);
  counter++;
 }
 Monomial::~Monomial()
 {
  counter--;
 }
 void Monomial::setCoff(int x)
 {
 coff = x;
 }
  void Monomial::setExpo(int x)
 {
 expo = x;
 }
  int Monomial::getCoff() const
 {
return coff;
 }
 int Monomial::getExpo() const
 {
return expo;
}

int Monomial::getNumberOfMonomials()
{
return counter;
 }

 const Monomial& Monomial:: operator = (const Monomial& right)
 {
  coff = right.coff;
  expo = right.expo;
  return (*this);
  }


 string Monomial:: operator+(const Monomial& right)
 {
   if (right.getExpo() == this->getExpo()) {

      this->setCoff(this->getCoff() + right.getCoff());

        return "True";
    }

   return "False";
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This usually means that this part of the code was optimized away by the compiler. But it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Can you expand your question and provide a minimal complete example, i.e. something that can be pasted into a file to be compiled and reproduce the issue? In general, I would also recommend to not use manual memory management instead of e.g. `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Your screenshot looks perfectly fine.  Everything shown in this screenshot is exactly as expected.  You thought that we will just look at it and immediately guess what the problem is, but this ain't happening.  And that's not a coincidence: a picture is never enough to explain a problem.  You also have to explain precisely what the problem is ***in your own words.***  Please tell us, in great detail, what you expected to happen, and what is happening instead.  (Spell out what you are seeing in the picture if necessary.)

Comment: (Hint: your problem is a purely technical issue which in all certainty has nothing to do with monomials and exponents and monomers and coefficients, so please spare us from that stuff and cut to the chase.)

Comment: Are you sure that object exist? Can you set breakpoint in line 8, is result the same? Maybe you use Release configuration of library? Your topic header confuses - this is not OOP question - would be great to rephrase. Notation of polynomial is difficult to read and likely they are not relevant

Comment: Is your program working? If not, please post a [mcve]. If it does work, what other problem is there?